# make dropdowns next to each other in bootstrap nav-bar

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, nav

I have trouble to using nav-bar Bootstrap I'm trying to put two dropdowns next to each other on lift side of view port,
the bootstrap I'm using is rtl,
I got such navbar bootstrap like this :

```html
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark">

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- Links -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav float-right">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
            </li>
          
        </ul>
        <div class="bg-danger flex-row">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                       data-toggle="dropdown"
                       aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button"
                       data-toggle="dropdown"
                       aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

i want two dropdowns with `.bg-danger` links goes to each other ... How i should do it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the html code, put both `<li>` into single `<ul>`

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark">

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- Links -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav float-right">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
        <div class="bg-danger flex-row">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                       data-toggle="dropdown"
                       aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button"
                       data-toggle="dropdown"
                       aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Let me know if you face any issue.